# Kendo TabStrip: Rendering Action into tab in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've been trying to render and Action **@Html.RenderAction(...)** into the **.Text()** of a Kendo Tab Strip with out success.

Is there a way to render a full action into a tab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
  .Name("tabMain")
  .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add()
               .Text("My Tab Title")
               .Content(Html.Action("Index","MyChildController").ToString());
      })
  )
```

Trick is to call  **.ToString** on the **Html.Action** call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use `LoadContentFrom`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabMain")
    .Items(items => {
        items.Add()
            .Text("My Tab Title")
            .LoadContentFrom("Index","MyChildController"));
  })
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing it, and in this case using Html.RenderAction is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
  .Name("tabMain")
  .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add()
               .Text("My Tab Title")
               .Content(@<text> @{Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller", new (or nothing) {data ="" });} </text>);
      })
  )
```